# How to launch new activity or task from onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, voice-recognition

I´m trying to use the VoiceRecognition sample for sending voice recognized text to an internet bot. All I need is to send info to an URL and get the html code.
I found a problem trying to start httpclient inside onActivityResult, and I don´t know how to solve it.
This is the code:

```
public class BkVRMobileActivity extends Activity
{

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private ListView wordsList;
    private TextView texto1;
    private TextView texto2;

    /**
     * Called with the activity is first created.
     */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.voice_recog);

    ImageButton speakButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.speakButton);
    wordsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    texto1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    texto2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    // Disable button if no recognition service is present
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
            new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
    if (activities.size() == 0)
    {
        speakButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

}

/**
 * Handle the action of the button being clicked
 */
public void speakButtonClicked(View v)
{
    startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
    System.out.println("--al lio --");
   }

/**
 * Fire an intent to start the voice recognition activity.
 */
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Reconocimiento de Voz activado...");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Handle the results from the voice recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)

    {
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
        RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        //wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,matches));
        texto1.setText(matches.get(0));

        String laurl = "http://www.pandorabots.com/pandora/talk-xml?input=" + matches.get(0) + "&botid=9cd68de58e342fb8";

        //open the url using httpclient for reading html source
        getXML(laurl);

        //System.out.println(laurl);



      }

   //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public String getXML(String url){
    String log = null;
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create HTTP Client
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); // Set the action you want to do
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // Executeit
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
        InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the response
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read line by line
            sb.append(line + "\n");

        String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here

        is.close(); // Close the stream
        texto2.setText(resString);


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        log = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        log = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
    }

    return log;
```

}

}

Comment: I get this error:/AndroidRuntime(10618): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1234, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {prototipos.gneis.bk/prototipos.gneis.bk.BkVRMobileActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

getXML needs to run on a separate thread as it does network requests (which can take a long time) which, on the UI thread will cause ANRs

Something like:

```
public String getXML(String url){
    new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
                private String doInBackgroundThread(String... params)
                {
                    try {

                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create HTTP Client
                        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(params[0]); // Set the action you want to do
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // Executeit
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
                        InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the response
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read line by line
                            sb.append(line + "\n");

                        String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here

                        is.close(); // Close the stream
                        return resString;
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result)
                {
                    texto2.setText(result);
                }
            }.execute(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks finally I did something like that. A new thread was the solution